# How to display Django input data on second page

Tags: python, django

i have easy Django view which displays text which user will type in input. Now this text is displaying on this same page without changing address (scraping.html), but i would like to display it on new page (scrapingscore.html). How am i able to do that? I read about HttpResponseRedirect and tried do it, but it didn't work and i am confused.

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'scraping.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                text = form.cleaned_data.get('post')
                form = HomeForm()

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(label='search', max_length=100)
```

scraping.html

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload text</button>
    </form>
    {{ text }}
{% endblock %}
```

edit:

now my code looks like:

urls.py

```
path('scraping', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='scraping'),
path('scrapingscore', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='scrapingscore'),
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'scraping.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                text = form.cleaned_data.get('post')
                form = HomeForm()
        c = {text: 'bar'}
        return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', context = c)
```

and i added '{{text}}' to scrapingscore.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display that data on a new page then do the following.

1. In URLS.conf define a URL that will redirect to a given method in
   views.py
2. In the method, you need to create a context, which will hold that
       data you want to render to the new page.
3. Finally, simply call the render method to display the HTML page you
       want with the data that you would like to pass as a context (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/)).

Views.py method should look like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    #set your data here
    c = {key_data: 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context = c)
```

Now on your `scrapingscore.html`, render the data as

`{{key_data}}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, i read your directions and link which you gave, i tried to do it by myself but the website is not redirecting to 'scrapingscore' - i edited first post and i added at the bottom how urls.py and views.py look like now. I am not sure about urls.py, i added this same view to both websites but should i did like this in urls?

Comment: You seem to be using class base views, I would recommend using functions base views as that's my preference.  see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: Is this solved? If so please accept the answer to show that it's been solved.